# Scala: Derive correct child class from abstract parent class parameters

Tags: oop, scala, inheritance

I'm new to scala and having some inheritance issues...
My NodeVisitor class is unable to differentiate between "b1" and "b2" in GreenBasket and provides and error stating that there is no method "visit" in Basket.
GreenBasket must be able to hold GreenBasket or OrangeBasket objects with "b1" and "b2".
How am I able to call the appropriate "visit" method depending on the type of "b1" and "b2"?
Thank you.

```
trait Visitor{
  def visit(o: OrangeBasket): Int
  def visit(g: GreenBasket): Int
}

sealed abstract class Basket() {
  def accept(visitor: Visitor): Unit
}

case class OrangeBasket(count: Int, kilos: Double) extends Basket(){
  def this(count: Int) = this(count, 0)
  def accept(visitor: Visitor) = visitor.visit(this)
}

case class GreenBasket(b1: Basket, b2: Basket) extends Basket(){
  def this(b1: Basket) = this(b1, null)
  def this() = this(null)
  def accept(visitor: Visitor) = visitor.visit(this)
}

class NodeVisitor() extends Visitor{
  def visit(o: OrangeBasket) = 1
  def visit(g: GreenBasket) = this.visit(g.b1) + this.visit(g.b2) + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you should call the methods differently. How about this:

```
class NodeVisitor() extends Visitor{
  def visit(o: OrangeBasket) = 1
  def visit(g: GreenBasket) = g.b1.accept(this) + g.b2.accept(this) + 1
}
```

Note that you should change the accept method signature.